# loop through multiple dataframes and create datetime index then join dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, loops, join, datetimeindex

I have 9 dataframes of different lengths but similar formats. Each dataframe has a `year`, `month`, and `day` column with dates that span from `1/1/2009-12/31/2019`, but some dataframes are missing data for some days. I would like to build one large dataframe with a DateTime Index, but I am having trouble creating a loop to convert the year, month, and day columns to a datetime index for each dataframe, and don't know which function to use to join the dataframes together. I have one dataframe called `Temp` that has all 4017 lines of data for every day of the 11 year period but the rest of the dataframes are missing some dates.

```
import pandas as pd

#just creating some sample data to make it easier

Temp = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2009,2009,2009,2010,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012,2013,2013,2013,
2014,2014,2014,2015,2015,2015],'month':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
'day':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
'T1':[20,21,25,28,30,33,39,35,34,34,31,30,27,24,20,21,25,28,30,33,39],
'T2':[33,39,35,34,34,31,30,27,24,20,21,25,28,30,33,39,20,21,25,28,30]})

WS = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2009,2009,2010,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012,2013,2013,2013,
2014,2014,2014,2015,2015,2015],'month':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
'day':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
'WS1':[5.4,5.1,5.2,4.3,4.4,4.4,1.2,1.5,1.6,2.3,2.5,3.1,2.5,4.6,4.4,4.4,1.2,1.5],
'WS2':[5.4,5.1,4.4,4.4,1.2,1.5,1.6,2.3,2.5,5.2,4.3,4.4,4.4,1.2,1.5,1.6,2.3,2.5]})

RH = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2009,2009,2010,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012,2013,2013,2013,
2014,2014,2014],'month':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
'day':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
'RH1':[33,38,30,45,52,60,61,66,60,59,30,45,52,60,61], 
'RH2':[33,38,59,30,45,52,60,61,30,45,52,60,61,66,60]})
```

Okay, so far what I have tried was to first create a loop that would convert the year, month, and day columns into a DateTime index and drop the remaining year, month, and day columns.

```
df = [Temp, WS, RH]

for dfs in df:
    dfs['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfs[['year','month','day']])
    dfs.set_index(['date'],inplace=True)
    dfs.drop(columns = ['year','month','day'],inplace=True)
```

But I keep getting errors that say `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not list` or `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`. Since I can't get over this issue, I'm having trouble discerning what to do after in order to merge all the dataframes together. I assume that I will have to set an index like `idx = pd.date_range('2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-12-31 23:00:00', freq='H')` and then reset_index for the dataframes that are missing the data. And then, couldn't I use a left-join or concatenate since they would all have the same index? **The dataframe examples given above do not have the desired date range, I just didn't know how else to make sample dataframes.**

Comment: You don't need a loop: `pd.to_datetime(Temp[["year", "month", "day"]])`

Comment: Yeah but I have to do that for 9 dataframes, seems tedious so I want to do it in one swift code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what are you looking for?

```
dfs = [Temp, WS, RH]

data = []
for df in dfs:
    data.append(df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df[["year", "month", "day"]]))
                  .drop(columns=["year", "month", "day"]))
out = pd.concat(data, axis="columns")
```

```
>>> out
            T1  T2  WS1  WS2   RH1   RH2
2009-01-01  20  33  5.4  5.4  33.0  33.0
2009-02-02  21  39  5.1  5.1  38.0  38.0
2009-03-03  25  35  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
2010-01-01  28  34  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
2010-02-02  30  34  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
2010-03-03  33  31  5.2  4.4  30.0  59.0
2011-01-01  39  30  4.3  4.4  45.0  30.0
2011-02-02  35  27  4.4  1.2  52.0  45.0
2011-03-03  34  24  4.4  1.5  60.0  52.0
2012-01-01  34  20  1.2  1.6  61.0  60.0
2012-02-02  31  21  1.5  2.3  66.0  61.0
2012-03-03  30  25  1.6  2.5  60.0  30.0
2013-01-01  27  28  2.3  5.2  59.0  45.0
2013-02-02  24  30  2.5  4.3  30.0  52.0
2013-03-03  20  33  3.1  4.4  45.0  60.0
2014-01-01  21  39  2.5  4.4  52.0  61.0
2014-02-02  25  20  4.6  1.2  60.0  66.0
2014-03-03  28  21  4.4  1.5  61.0  60.0
2015-01-01  30  25  4.4  1.6   NaN   NaN
2015-02-02  33  28  1.2  2.3   NaN   NaN
2015-03-03  39  30  1.5  2.5   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: does `pd.concat` automatically fill missing data with `NaN`?

Comment: Yes. From the doc: "Combine DataFrame objects with overlapping columns and return everything. Columns outside the intersection will be filled with NaN values."

Comment: @Heather.If you want to have a dataframe with all days between your first and your last dates, you can do: `out.reindex(pd.date_range(out.index.min(), out.index.max(), freq="D"))`